# Why i getting Highway.forward: `input` must be present when running : from elmoformanylangs import Embedder

Tags: python, elmo

I am trying to use ELMoForManyLangs programmatically, by using Embedder python object.

```
from elmoformanylangs import Embedder
e = Embedder('/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/158', batch_size = 64)
```

When I run, I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-11-e628da2114ae> in <module>()
----> 1 from elmoformanylangs import Embedder
      2 # e = Embedder('/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/158', batch_size = 64)

10 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/overrides/signature.py in ensure_all_positional_args_defined_in_sub(super_sig, sub_sig, super_type_hints, sub_type_hints, check_first_parameter, method_name)
    193         if super_param.kind == Parameter.VAR_POSITIONAL:
    194             if not sub_has_var_args:
--> 195                 raise TypeError(f"{method_name}: `{super_param.name}` must be present")
    196             continue
    197         if (

TypeError: Highway.forward: `input` must be present
```

Do you have any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. It seems to be a problem related to overrides package.
I solve downgrading the 'overrides' package in my virtual-env. In particular I switched from overrides==6.0.1 to overrides==3.1.0.

So you should try to do:

```
pip uninstall overrides
pip install overrides==3.1.0
```